# How to get Youtube video list and play while clicking the video

Tags: android, video, android-listview

I want to access Youtube videos and display the thumbnail of the video along with its title in a `ListView`. On clicking of the thumbnail, the video should be played. Can anyone suggest some sample program related to my need or link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below link to solve your problem. Please check the same.

http://it-ride.blogspot.in/2010/04/android-youtube-intent.html